# Integral reducing

Tags: integration

[image: Provided Solution]

I'm not following all the steps to this integral. I understand the exponent manipulation between steps 1 and 2, but I don't understand how the integral goes from step 2 to step 3.

(i.e. I don't understand how the numerator of the exponent went from $ (x-\mu)^2 - 2\sigma^2ux $ to $ [x-(\mu + \sigma^2u)]^2 - (2\sigma^2u\mu+\sigma^4u^2) $. )

I understand that the idea is to manipulate the function so that part of it can be factored out, I just don't understand the mathematical steps that took place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completing the square:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x-\mu)^2 - 2\sigma^2ux &=x^2-2\mu x+\mu^2-2\sigma^2u x\\
&=(x-(\mu+\sigma^2u))^2-(\mu+\sigma^2u)^2+\mu^2\\
&= (x-(\mu + \sigma^2u))^2 - (2\sigma^2u\mu+\sigma^4u^2).
\end{aligned}
$$